# XSLT: mix nodes if they have same id

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

i have xml with similar structure:

```
<Info>
<parents>
    <parent1>
        <id>1</id>
    </parent1>
    <parent2>
        <id>2</id>
    </parent2>
</parents>

<children>

    <child>
        <id>1</id>
        <parentID>
            1
        </parentID>
        <someInfoFromOneNode>
            qqq
        </someInfoFromOneNode>
    </child>
    <child>
        <id>1</id>
        <parentID>
            1
        </parentID>
        <someInfoFromAnOtherNode>
            qqq
        </someInfoFromAnOtherNode>
    </child>
    <child>
        <id>2</id>
        <parentID>
            2
        </parentID>
        <someInfoFromOneNode>
            qqq
        </someInfoFromOneNode>
    </child>
    <child>
        <id>2</id>
        <parentID>
            2
        </parentID>
        <someInfoFromAnOtherNode>
            qqq
        </someInfoFromAnOtherNode>
    </child>
</children>
</Info>
```

i need to get xml with that structure:

```
<Info>

<parent>
    <id>1</id>
    <children>
        <chidl>
            <id>1</id>
            <someInfoFromOneNode>
                 qqq
            </someInfoFromOneNode>
            <someInfoFromAnOtherNode>
                  qqq
            </someInfoFromAnOtherNode>
        </chidl>
    </children>
</parent>
<parent>
    <id>2</id>
    <children>
        <chidl>
            <id>2</id>
             <someInfoFromOneNode>
                 qqq
            </someInfoFromOneNode>
            <someInfoFromAnOtherNode>
                  qqq
            </someInfoFromAnOtherNode>
        </chidl>
    </children>
</parent>

</Info>
```

So i need to collect all children of one parent and in addition collect info related to one child. I've tried to filter children like this and displayed at least children ids(i keep the parentId):

```
<children>
          <xsl:for-each select="/Info/children/child">
                  <xsl:if test="./price_groups_id = $parentId and not(./id = preceding-sibling::id)">
                          <child>
                              <id>
                                 <xsl:value-of select="./id"/>

                               </id
                          </child>
                   </xsl:if>
           </xsl:for-each>

 </children>
```

But it only filters children by parent id and duplicate them, so current result is that:

```
    <Info>

<parent>
    <id>1</id>
    <children>
        <child>
            <id>1</id>
        </child>
        <child>
            <id>1</id>
        </child>
    </children>
</parent>
<parent>
    <id>2</id>
    <children>
        <child>
            <id>2</id>
        </child>
        <child>
            <id>2</id>
        </child>
    </children>
</parent>

</Info>
```

What can i do to check previous node id and filter by it?

Comment: *"i need to collect all children of one parent and in addition collect info related to one child."* That's not what your output shows. You have collected only children that have `someInfo`. In any case, I suggest you use a **key** to get the children of each parent.

Comment: I just tried to make my xml structure shorter, okay, i edited the question

Comment: @michael.hor257k Do you mean Muenchian Method?

Comment: I meant a simple key to get the parent's child by their `parentID`. But if you also want to group the children by their `id` then you may need to use Muenchian grouping as well. The example is ambiguous, it's not clear if the same parent can have children with different `id `values. If yes, then do Muenchian grouping using `concat(id, '|', parentID)` as the key.